# Imtech.Pager Issue in IE

Tags: internet-explorer

I have used the client side pagination code from http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/35/index.html
This code is working fine in firefox but in IE it is showing blank div. Here is my pagination code

```
 this.showPage = function(page) {
    this.currentPage = page;
    var html = '';

   this.paragraphs.slice((page-1) * this.paragraphsPerPage,
        ((page-1)*this.paragraphsPerPage) + this.paragraphsPerPage).each(function() {
    // here I am getting $(this).html() blank in IE when I click on pagination links        
        html += "<div class='main_result_container'>" + $(this).html() + "</div>";

   });
```

Please help.

Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the changes I made to "imtech_pager.js" to get it to work in IE:

1. I created an empty object to store the paragraph items:

   **var pageItems = [];**
2. Then I loop over all the paragraph elements and store
   them in that "pageItems" object:

   **$('p.z').each(function(i,e){
       if($(this).html().length > 0)
           pageItems.push($(this).html());
   });**
3. Finally in the "this.showPage" function (near line #26), replace the "**elem.innerHTML**" (near line #23) with "**pageItems[i]**"

This took me forever to debug and was so annoying, to top it off I was implementing this inside SharePoint. Anyways hope this helps!